# Add taxonomy term in popup

Tags: forms, javascript, taxonomy-terms

I have a **select list** with some options. But now I also want an option `Other`. And when you select the `Other` option there has to open a **pop-up screen** with **the add term to vocabulary form** in it. The term should not be added directly to the vocabulary, it should be "disabled" first so the administrator can approve them.

I know how to get the taxonomy form (taxonomy_form_term, drupal_get_form, drupal_render_form) but I have some other questions:

- How can I open the popup and show call the function in my module to render the form? Should I add another option to my select list?
- How can I make sure when you add it, it doesn't add directly to the vocabulary (admin has to click approve)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, set an event listener to bind when the `other` option is selected, and then display your popup. I would suggest **setting a custom state** (see the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states)) and listening for that state. The [example given in the states API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7) explains better:

> Each remote condition is a key/value pair specifying conditions on the
>   other element that need to be met to apply the state to the element:
>
> ```
> array(   
>   'visible' => array(
>     ':input[name="remote_checkbox"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),   ), )
> ```
>
> For example, to show a textfield only when a checkbox is checked:
>
> ```
>  $form['toggle_me'] = array(   
>    '#type' => 'checkbox',   
>    '#title' => t('Tick this box to type'), 
>  ); $form['settings'] = array(   
>      '#type' => 'textfield',   
>      '#states' => array(
>      // Only show this field when the 'toggle_me' checkbox is enabled.
>      'visible' => array(
>        ':input[name="toggle_me"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
>  ),   
> ),
> ```
>
> );

[jQuery UI Dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) would be a good solution for the popup.

For the second part, there is a module to handle just this situation, so that taxonomy terms can be moderated and approved. [Taxonomy Other](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_other):

> Use case example: You have a taxonomy vocabulary called 'Organization
>   type' and you want to allow users to be able to choose '- Other -' and
>   add their own type. You want to use a simple select list and to keep
>   the list small to encourage people to use the types you've provided.